# I can't have access to PhpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, mamp

I tried to add a password for 'root', when having access to localhost with MAMP, and, don't knowing how to enter, I added a password and now I have this problem:

Link for the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULCrH.png

Please tell me what can I do to fix the problem!